# Significance of CSS classes form-horizontal, form-group, and form-control?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

Where do these classes originate?

- Part of HTML5 or CSS3 spec?
- ASP.NET CSS classes? (MVC5 View Scaffolding automatically creates elements with these classes for "Create" and "Edit" views)
- Bootstrap also configures these classes and every Google result seems to mention bootstrap along with these classes.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that ASP.NET MVC would be catering to bootstrap like this if it's a bootstrap thing.

Answer (score 1):

The class names come from Bootstrap. They are documented [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms). Bootstrap is in fact [the default CSS framework in the new ASP.NET MVC project templates](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio).

The HTML and CSS specs don't define or reserve any class names (at least, not as far as I'm aware).